# Ignoring zeroes and blanks while index-matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an excel workbook that uses INDEX-MATCH in order to copy values from one sheet to another `=INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0);1)`. The tough part is that the column that is being indexed contains a lot of zeroes and blanks as such:

[image]

This results in getting the zeroes instead of the actual value that I need. I am not allowed to change the structure of the source since I get that sheet from an external database.

I tried using `=INDEX(IF(AND(Table2[Budget]<>"";Table2<>"0");Table2[Budget]);MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0);1)` to ignore the unwanted values but the result is still the same.

Comment: Control the result of the index() not its input.

Comment: What is your excel version? You may try `FILTER()` function.

Comment: @Harun24hr i use Excel 2016, FILTER is not supported

Comment: Then `AGGREGATE()` may help.

Comment: @SolarMike you mean move the IF-AND outside, right? Something like this: =IF(AND(INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No)];0);1)=" ";INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No)];0);1)="0");INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No)];0);1))

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to leave the spaces blank where the value is either blank or 0 you can do 2 things depending on how the values are on the other cells.

If you don't have decimal numbers lower than 1 then you can do this:

=IF(INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0))<1;"";INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0)))

But if you want to show all numbers including decimal numbers you can do this which is a bit longer:

=IF(OR(INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0))="";INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0))=0);"";INDEX(Table2[Budget];MATCH([@ID-No];Table2[ID-No];0)))

Basically you are telling the formula that if the value is 0 or nothing then leave the space as nothing